# Debug unity android in rider, cannot find Android Player process

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, rider

see my screencast: https://youtu.be/JjtNrAR_bWM

it's very simple project with one script

```
public class TestDebugAndroid : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        var r = Application.platform;
        r = Application.platform;
    }
}
```

when i use rider > run > attach to unity process, I cannot find android emulator, 
and I find adb port from adb logcat with keyword "monooptions" 
and manually type this monooptions port, debug session cannot reach breakpoint
[image]

and it raise:

```
Failed to connect: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:56531
Unable to connect to 127.0.0.1
Please ensure that the player has 'Script Debugging' enabled and that the host '127.0.0.1' is reachable.
```

when i use visual studio > Debug > Attach to unity debugger, I can find android emulator device with same port in adb logcat, it work and can Find Android Player and debug session can reach breakpoint
[image]

so I think I miss some step in rider or rider miss some code to find android player, how to fix it

Comment: I'm also facing the same problem, did you find something?